# Why is it advised to disable relayhost when hosting mail server behind firewall?

Tags: email, postfix, firewall, email-server, e-mailrelay

I am trying to setup an MTA. While reading documentation I came across "Standard Configuration" for [Running Postfix behind a firewall](https://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#firewall).

I am confused on this part:

> IMPORTANT: do not specify a relayhost in main.cf.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Because if you open a relay, your mail server will be used for spam. Granted if it's behind a firewall so that only your internal network can ever see the MTA, this is not such a big deal; however, as soon as you expose an MTA that is an open relay to the Internet at large, you run the risk of becoming a major spam source. And as an MTA that's only visible within your personal private network is of very limited utility, the assumption is that you will be opening the MTA port to the wider internet at some point - by which time you may have forgotten fine details of your config.